# TabBarController inside NavigationController

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Imagine that we have multiview apllication which is controlled by Navigation Controller. We go from the first view to second by using pushViewController method and that's not a problem but then we need to move to the third view. And the third one is a view which looks like a TabBar. How do we do that? The third view is supposed to be controlled by TabBarController, isn't it?
So how to pass the control? I declared an outlet UITabBarController * tbc and connected it to TabBarController in xib file and then i tried this in viewDidLoad:
tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

and it shows nothing. 
Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit wierd.  Its more standard to have a tabBarController that switches views and some of those views may be navigation controllers.  But ...

Create the UITabBarController and push it.

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// create someView
[viewControllers addObject:someView];
// create someView2
[viewControllers addObject:someView2];


UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```

Then, from the tabBarContoller view, based on some action, you can choose to pop it:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wire it up in the storyboard editor in the latest version of Xcode.

However, since this is very much non-standard use of the controls, you would need a *very* good reason as to why you would want a UI like this.

And even then, Apple's review process might turn your app down if the interface is clunky.