# iOS put a TabbarViewController into a NavigationController but the navigationBar is nil

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

A is a subclass of TabbarViewController

```
A *a = [[A alloc] init];

B *b = [[B alloc] init];
C *C = [[C alloc] init];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:b,c, nil];
[a setViewControllers:viewControllers];

UINavigationController *nv =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:a];
nv.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:nv animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And in A.m: I find the a.navigationController.navigationBar is nil
I dont know why?

Comment: Are you trying to put TabBarController inside a NavigationController? Please, write your actual classes instead of A, B, C.

Comment: @Stas Yes, A is a subclass of TabbarViewController and I want to put A into a navigationController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you should create several NavigationController objects for each of TabBarController's tabs.

> When you create a navigation interface, you need to decide how you intend to use a navigation interface. Because it imposes an overarching organization on your data, you should only use it in these specific ways:
>
> Install it directly as a window’s root view controller.
>
> **Install it as the view controller of a tab in a tab bar interface.**
>
> Install it as one of the two root view controllers in a split view interface. (iPad only)
>
> Present it modally from another view controller.
>
> Display it from a popover. (iPad only)

If you still want 'TabBarController inside NavigationController' functionality, please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825931/tabbarcontroller-inside-navigationcontroller) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root) SO questions to find a proper solution.